# AngularJS search filter with other filters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have a code below:

```
<input type='text' ng-model="search.$">
<li ng-repeat="item in items" |filter:isExpired | filter:search>{{item.name}}</li>
```

Currently, items has a boolean attribute to indicate whether it is expired or not and the page displays all items that are NOT expired.

On search, I want to show ALL items including expired ones. Is there a way to toggle isExpired filter on search? Or would I need to develop my own custom filter? if so, can anyone give me an idea of an approach?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the filtering in the controller:

```
.controller('YourController', function($scope, $filter){

    $scope.getItems = function() {

        var filtered;

        if($scope.search) {

            filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.items, $scope.search);

        }
        else{

            filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.items, {isExpired: false});
        }


        return filtered;
    }
});
```

and then, your ng-repeat would look like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in getItems()">{{item.name}}</li>
```